# OpenCL: Determine if a Device is already running

Tags: opencl

First, i'm relativly new to OpenCL.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to determine at runtime if a device is already running another kernel.

**My Use-Case:** i've a host programm asynchron calling different OpenCL function, which may or may not use the same Device. There a functions which can run acceptable fast on CPU, so waiting for the Device to be ready can be a bottleneck. I want to determine if the Device is already in use, and if so run a fallback function on the CPU.

**Question 2:** If the anwser to Question 1 is no. Is there any other possibility, than writing my own Device-Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated API for querying whether a device is currently executing a kernel, but you can implement this yourself using event objects.

Whenever you enqueue a kernel, you can optionally retrieve an event object which identifies that command. Using `clGetEventInfo` and the `CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS` query, you can check whether a particular command has finished executing. By keeping a reference to the event object for the most recently enqueued kernel, you can use this API to check whether or not a device currently has pending kernel commands in its queue.

Of course, this only allows you to determine if there are pending kernels from *your* application - there is no way to check whether there are pending kernels from other OpenCL applications that might also be running on the system.

Comment: to bad! But what happens exactly if run kernel on a device already running? Is the processing stored in a waiting queue?

Comment: Yes, there is a command queue that all enqueue commands (kernels and memory operations) are submitted to.